String Manipulation Tools
Can somebody please explain to me this behaviour in python.
s = 'Hello World!'

s.find('') # 0
s.find('H') # 0

I really don't understand why the two should return the same index. Why shouldn't the second find() return 1 instead.

Same question, different language: String find function in C++ returns 0 if string passed as argument is empty

The string is 0-indexed in this context. As 'H' is at the start of the string you should not be surprised that s.find('H') returns 0

>>> s.find('H')
0

because s[0] is 'H', thus s[0:0 + 1] == 'H'. In other words, the string 'H' of length 1 occurs at position 0 in s

>>> s.find('')
0

because s[0:0 + 0] == ''. In other words, the string '' of length 0 occurs at position 0 in s

In fact:
>>> s.find('He')
0
>>> s.find('Hel')
0
>>> s.find('Hell')
0
>>> s.find('Hello')
0
>>> s.find('Hello w')
0

all return 0, because all these strings occur at the very beginning of s

The behavior you're seeing with str.find() in Python can definitely be a bit confusing at first.
s.find('') returns 0:
This is because when you search for an empty string (''), Python treats it like you're asking where does an empty string appear first in this string. Technically, an empty string can be found at every position in the string, including index 0. So it just returns 0 because that's the start of the string.
s.find('H') returns 0:
This one works as you'd expect. It looks for the character 'H' and returns 0 because that’s where 'H' is found.
So yeah, they both return 0, but for different reasons:
s.find('') is finding the empty string at the start (index 0),
s.find('H') finds 'H' at index 0 as well.
If you’re trying to search for the next occurrence after the first one, you can use the result of the first .find() to continue from there.
